# STM32F476G Disco, OpenOCD read version failed

Tags: openocd, stm32f7

I want to debug my programm and my debugger shows:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0-dev-00278-ga53935e-dirty (2017-05-09-09:25) 
Licensed under GNU GPL v2 
For bug reports, read 
http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html 
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_assert_srst 
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD 
adapter speed: 4000 kHz 
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100 
Info : clock speed 4000 kHz 
Error: read version failed 
in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should append because you haven't selected the good "plateform", you must put your debugger on "STM32F476" to provide enough power to your ST developement kit.